# Go AWS SDK v2 + SSO

Tags: go, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

Using the AWS SDK for Go (v2), I'm trying to get authenticated using my SSO account. It seems to be working, insofar as I'm able to dump my profile config, but as soon as I call `GetCallerIdentity()` on the `sts` client, I get an invalid token id error. On my laptop, I am logged in to the same SSO profile that I'm trying to use and I can run `aws sts get-caller-identity` from the command line just fine.

```
func whoAmI() {
        ctx := context.TODO()

        fmt.Printf("AWS profile: '%s'\n", os.Getenv("AWS_PROFILE")) // shows the name of the profile under which i'm currently authenticated just for reference

        cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(
            ctx,
            config.WithSharedConfigProfile("same-profle-name-as-above"),
        )
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", cfg) // shows me all the right stuff (keys, region, etc.)

        client := sts.NewFromConfig(cfg)
        identity, err := client.GetCallerIdentity(
            ctx,
            &sts.GetCallerIdentityInput{},
        )
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("%+v", identity)

        return nil
}
```

Result:

```
operation error STS: GetCallerIdentity, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: <whatever>, api error InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid
```

What am I missing here? This code is pulled nearly verbatim from some example code. As mentioned, I can run the analogous awscli command with no issue and I have full admin access to the account. I've also tried fetching something from SecretsManager with a similar result (invalid token).

Any nudge in the right direction would be helpful - my current trial and error path is getting frustrating. :-)

Comment: It think, the `config.LoadDefaultConfig()` function doesn't fetch the SSO credentials by default. To use SSO with AWS SDK for Go v2, you need to create an `aws.Config` object with the SSO credentials explicitly.

Comment: to load profile `config.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx, config.WithSharedConfigProfile(profile), config.WithoutCredentials())` and then create new provider using `sso.NewSSOCredentialProvider` and retrive the profile. I haven't tried myself this code but this might help you.  Here is go [playground link](https://goplay.tools/snippet/qzxdxolmh8E) this is untested code might need some changes.

Comment: Thanks! I don't see that `config.WithoutCredentials()` is a thing, though. Am I looking in the wrong place? https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config#pkg-overview

Comment: Everywhere I look makes me think I'm doing this correctly. For example, the [ssocreds module](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials@v1.13.20/ssocreds#hdr-Loading_AWS_SSO_credentials_with_the_AWS_shared_configuration_file) clearly states that, "The provider in this package does not initiate or perform the AWS SSO login flow. The SDK provider expects that you have already performed the SSO login flow using AWS CLI using the "aws sso login" command, or by some other mechanism." I have logged in with that profile using the `aws sso login` command.